# Returning an Array from a C++ Function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, syntax, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [howto return a array in a c++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264304/howto-return-a-array-in-a-c-method)

How can an array be returned from a function?  I'm going for an effect like this:

```
int getArray()
{
    return {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

`...`

`int myArray[5] = getArray();`

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845819/how-can-i-return-an-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302279/return-an-array-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138660/in-c-how-do-i-return-an-array-of-objects-from-a-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253106/how-can-i-return-an-array-in-c-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either dynamic allocation or `std::vector`. You can't return an array by value.

Comment: Then how do things like `myString.c_str` work?

Comment: `c_str()` doesn't return array, it returns a pointer (to an internal buffer)